# How to adjust the scale of cloud graph in R/lattice?

Tags: r, lattice

I have to plot a 3D bars graph in `R` using `Lattice` package. However i can not find the method to increase the scale of the graph to fit the frame.

Here is the example data:

```
myData<-read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
  PControl       PmM1      PmM5     PmM10  
  -10  -10.00000  -10.0000  -10.0000  
  -10  -90.07893 -107.9128 -133.9970  
  -10 -171.05350 -238.1698 -322.1791  
  -10 -252.29850 -350.5628 -447.1163  
")
```

[image]

Comment: Sample data, but no code.Your pseudo-3d barplot is not a standard offering in lattice, so you must have cobbled something together. I could be wrong but to my eyes it does not seem to be either a `cloud` or a `wireframe` product.

Comment: It's a modified cloud 3d bars plot.

Comment: The code is uploaded to google drive. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byz-w-7ptPyZVVVYWUhYWnRwYVE/view?usp=sharing).@BondedDust

Comment: The code throws an error on my current version of R. Generally the first argument to cloud will be a formula, although a matrix may succeed. Your first argument is a minus sign followed by a dataframe name. If I apply `as.matrix` to that argument I get an error saying that `fff` is not found. Try starting R with no data and then run the code you have offered until you are able to offer a minimal working example.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind reply! I made a mistake in the code i uploaded to the google drive. The 'fff' should be replaced with 'myData' and the code will be worked. The minimal code is `cloud(-myData,   
 panel.3d.cloud = panel.3dbars,  
 zlim = c(0,-min(myData)),  
 xlim = c(0,5),  
 scales = list(arrows = FALSE)  
)`  . @BondedDust